# USB device not enumerated properly in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, usb, beagleboard

My setup :

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot with windows 7.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux nikhil 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

USB devices:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What I am doing: trying to understand UART driver in kernel and want to write a custom one.

Problem: 
I have a beaglebone black board, connected via a usb cable to power it up, one usb to uart cable. One day back it was working well and I was able to get uart prints via /dev/ttyUSB0 port. Today if I connect all of this setup I am getting this error in `dmesg`:

```
[  137.719417] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  137.791482] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  137.967627] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  138.143778] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  138.215838] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  138.391989] usb 2-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[  138.568138] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  138.976482] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 5, error -32
[  139.048602] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[  139.456902] usb 2-1.2: device not accepting address 6, error -32
[  139.456999] usb 2-1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
[  357.890716] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  358.180986] usb 1-1.2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[  358.180992] usb 1-1.2: can't read configurations, error -71
[  670.985054] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  671.275398] usb 1-1.2: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -71
[  671.275404] usb 1-1.2: can't read configurations, error -71
```

Somewhere on internet it was mentioned that error -32 is a usb power problem. Also I came to know that while enumerating the device, host sends read write packets and to allocate an address, that are seen as failed in `dmesg`.

Is there any solution for it, or my hardware has failed? If failed which one is most likely to be corrupted, beaglebone black board or usb cable?

P.S.: However I tested hardware functionality on windows 7 tera term. There it doesn't show any problem. Another thing is I can see serial device as `/dev/ttyACM0`, not `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Due to this I can not see early prints of u-boot only I can see prints when it comes to login prompt.
Checked the mini usb cable power. It showed 4.84 to 5.15 volts.